# The question about three-dimensional array and assigning in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I recently started to learn Go.
I have a task from JetBrains: "Declare a three-dimensional array of the float32 type with the size of 4 by 4 by 4 elements, assign 88.6 to its [1][0][2] element, and finally print the array to the console."
I declared an array like this:

```
var array = [4][4][4]float32{}
```

Now i have few problems:

1. When i'm trying to assign a value 88.6 to the array i get an error: "'88.6' (type untyped float) cannot be represented by the type [4]float32"
2. I can't understand task. Do I need to assign [0][1][2] elements in **every** array to 88.6 or [0][1][2] dimensional arrays should be assigned to "88.6"

I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the task is asking you to assign to only one element in the array:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  var array [4][4][4]float32
  array[1][0][2] = 88.6
  fmt.Println(array)
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[[0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]] [[0 0 88.6 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]] [[0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]] [[0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]]]
```